# Recursive unassigned lambda in python

Tags: python, recursion, lambda, anonymous-function

Can we code a recursive lambda in python without assigning it to any variable ?

Like this:

```
print((lambda x: 1 if x <= 1 else x*self(x-1))(5))
```

I know that this code won't do anything. Specially the self(x-1). Any idea how to do that?

I just want to print the factorial of 5 in one line using a recursive lambda.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: No, Python lambdas were not designed to do that.

Longer answer #1: pass the function in as the first argument to itself.

```
>>> (lambda f: lambda x: f(f,x))(lambda self, x: 1 if x<=1 else x*self(self, x-1))(5)
120
```

Get it? No? Let's unpack this.

```
def save_func(self):
    def call_with_self_and(x):
        return self(self, x)
    return call_with_self_and

@save_func
def factorial(self, x):
    return 1 if x<=1 else x*self(self, x-1)

factorial(5)  # 120
```

It's the same as the one-liner, but I gave everything names. Lambdas have no way to refer to themselves in Python, but you can pass in the lambda as its own first argument. That's what `call_with_self_and()` does for you: assuming you already have a self, it calls `self(self, x)`, while only requiring `x` as an argument. That's the function you want.

And `save_func()` is the factory function that creates the function you want out of the function you have (almost). It takes the `self` and returns the `call_with_self_and()`.

The "almost" part is that the function you have needs a tweak, from this:

```
lambda x: 1 if x <= 1 else x*self(x-1)
```

To this:

```
lambda self, x: 1 if x<=1 else x*self(self, x-1)
```

See what I did there? I passed `self` in as the first argument to `self` when recursing.

The search term you're looking for is "Y combinator".

---

Longer answer #2: Python lambdas were not designed to do that, but we can implement it.

This helper function can give a lambda an explicit recursion parameter.

```
 def R(f):
     def self(*a,**kw):
         return f(self, *a, **kw)
     return self
```

Use it like so:

```
print(R(lambda self, x: 1 if x <= 1 else x*self(x-1))(5))
```